cant get my data from my api with chainlink functions
It's me <@1220308975564886016> again with some chainlink functions problems that need to be solved. I am currently working on a project for the hackathon. Haven't deployed my contracts that require chainlink functions yet but still decided not to hardcode my data on chain, hence my api calls with chainlink functions is needed to work for my project functionality to be complete. For now, I try to simulate the js code to run on my pc and give me the desired outputs but to no avail.
I have the following code:
getProductInformationSource.js
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.10.0');

const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();

const productId = args[0];

const url = `https://sanctum-link-worker.danny-b41.workers.dev/api/v1/product/${productId}`; // api url goes here

const req = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url,
})

const res = await req;

if (res.error) {
    console.log(res.error);
    throw Error("Request failed");
}

const productPrice = Number(res.data.price);
const productQuantity = Number(res.data.stock);
const productDescription = res.data.description;
const encoded = abiCoder.encode([`uint256`, `uint256`, `uint256`, `string`], [parseInt(productId), productPrice, productQuantity, productDescription]);
return ethers.getBytes(encoded);

getKYCVerifiedStage0Source.js
const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.10.0');

const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();

const sanctumLinkIdentity = args[0];

const url = `https://sanctum-link-worker.danny-b41.workers.dev/api/v1/identity/${sanctumLinkIdentity}`; // api url goes here

const req = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
    url,
})

const res = await req;

if (res.error) {
    console.log(res.error);
    throw Error("Request failed");
}

const dataTypeArray = [`string`]
const dataValueArray = [sanctumLinkIdentity]

const KYCVerified = res.data

for (const key in kycVerifiedStage0) {
    if (kycVerifiedStage0.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        dataTypeArray.push(`string`);
        dataValueArray.push(kycVerifiedStage0[key]);
    }
}

const encoded = abiCoder.encode(dataTypeArray, dataValueArray)

return ethers.getBytes(encoded)

Functions-request-config.js
const fs = require("fs")

require("@chainlink/env-enc").config()

const Location = {
    Inline: 0,
    Remote: 1,
}

const CodeLanguage = {
    JavaScript: 0,
}

const ReturnType = {
    uint: "uint256",
    uint256: "uint256",
    int: "int256",
    int256: "int256",
    string: "string",
    bytes: "Buffer",
    Buffer: "Buffer",
}

// Configure the request by setting the fields below
const requestConfig = {
    // String containing the source code to be executed
    source: fs.readFileSync("./getProductInformationSource.js").toString(),
    //source: fs.readFileSync("./API-request-example.js").toString(),
    // Location of source code (only Inline is currently supported)
    codeLocation: Location.Inline,
    // Optional. Secrets can be accessed within the source code with `secrets.varName` (ie: secrets.apiKey). The secrets object can only contain string values.
    secrets: {},
    // Optional if secrets are expected in the sourceLocation of secrets (only Remote or DONHosted is supported)
    //   secretsLocation: Location.DONHosted,
    // Args (string only array) can be accessed within the source code with `args[index]` (ie: args[0]).
    args: ["0"],
    // Code language (only JavaScript is currently supported)
    codeLanguage: CodeLanguage.JavaScript,
    // Expected type of the returned value
    expectedReturnType: ReturnType.bytes,
    // expectedReturnType: ReturnType.string,
    // Redundant URLs which point to encrypted off-chain secrets
    secretsURLs: [],
}

module.exports = requestConfig

Functions-simulate-script.js
const { simulateScript } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const requestConfig = require('./Functions-request-config');

async function main() {
    const { responseBytesHexstring, capturedTerminalOutput, errorString } = await simulateScript(requestConfig);

    console.log(responseBytesHexstring);
    console.log(errorString)
    console.log(capturedTerminalOutput);
}

// node Functions-simulate-script.js
main();

package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        "simulate": "node ./Functions-simulate-script.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chainlink/env-enc": "^1.0.5",
        "@chainlink/functions-toolkit": "^0.2.8"
    }
}

FunctionsSource.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

/**
 * @author <@1220308975564886016>
 * @notice This contract will contain the js source codes that chainlink functions will run
 */

contract FunctionsSource {
    string public getKYCVerifiedStage0 = "const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.10.0');"
        "const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();" "const sanctumLinkIdentity = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "    url: `https://sanctum-link-worker.danny-b41.workers.dev/api/v1/identity/${sanctumLinkIdentity}`"
        "});" "const dataTypeArray = [`string`];"
        "const dataValueArray = [sanctumLinkIdentity];"
        "const kycVerifiedStage0 = apiResponse.data;"
        "for (const key in kycVerifiedStage0) {"
        "    if (kycVerifiedStage0.hasOwnProperty(key)) {"
        "        dataTypeArray.push(`string`);"
        "        dataValueArray.push(kycVerifiedStage0[key]);"
        "    }"
        "}"
        "const encoded = abiCoder.encode(dataTypeArray, dataValueArray);"
        "return ethers.getBytes(encoded);";

    string public getProductInformation = "const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.10.0');"
        "const abiCoder = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder();" "const productId = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "    url: `https://sanctum-link-worker.danny-b41.workers.dev/api/v1/product/${productId}`"
        "});" "const productPrice = Number(apiResponse.data.price);"
        "const productQuantity = Number(apiResponse.data.stock);"
        "const productDescription = apiResponse.data.description;"
        "const encoded = abiCoder.encode([`uint256`, `uint256`, `uint256`, `string`], [parseInt(productId), productPrice, productQuantity, productDescription]);"
        "return ethers.getBytes(encoded);";
}

package-lock.json (Cant upload the file here)
When I run this: node Functions-simulate-script.js
I get the error:
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
undefined
syntax error, RAM exceeded, or other error
error: Module not found "file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1716961195015.ts".
My question is that has the RAM been exceeded (which I doubt because the getProductInformationSource.js returns more of uint than string). Also, if it is a problem with my code, please do share how I can fix the code. If the issue then boils down to 256 bytes limit, then I guess I will need to deploy the contracts. I will also need help deploying the contracts to sepolia or avalanche fuji. Is it the same process as deploying other contracts on Remix? Thanks guys for your assistance in advance.

Please check this file to encode custom response: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples/blob/main/functions-examples/examples/3-custom-response/source.js. I think the line const { ethers } = await import('npm:ethers@6.10.0'); might be the problem since there is a RAM limit in CL node environment.

In your getProductInformationSource.js, the res.data.price (i.e., one of the fields in your API response) is of type float. So, in order to encode the same as uint256, you've to remove the decimal places, and that you can simply achieve using ethers.parseUnits() like:
const productPriceInWei = ethers.parseUnits(res.data.price.toString());

That will basically format the productPrice in 18-decimals (i.e., wei) format.
Example: 99.99 would become 99990000000000000000.
For testing, you can use the eth-converter by entering the actual price in Ether field, and getting the corresponding formatted price in Wei field.
And, while decoding the same on the client side i.e., in your frontend,  you can convert it back to float using ethers.formatUnits() as:
const productPrice = parseFloat(ethers.formatUnits(productPriceInWei));


And, your getKYCVerifiedStage0Source.js is failing due to the 256 bytes limit, so you need to select some of the key-value pairs (probably 2 or 3 depending on the content size of the corresponding values), so as to make sure that the resultant encoded data remains within 256 bytes limit.

I resolved the problem by reinstalling Deno.
Because Deno was not able to read the temporare "file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts" in SimulateScript.js situated in nodes_modules/@chainlink/functions-toolkit/dist/SimulateScript/simulateScript.js.
"file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts". If this file with a different number every time is created sussessfully in
const createScriptTempFile = (source) => {
    const tmpDir = os_1.default.tmpdir();
    const sandboxText = fs_1.default.readFileSync(path_1.default.join(__dirname, '/deno-sandbox/sandbox.ts'), 'utf8');
    const script = sandboxText.replace('//INJECT_USER_CODE_HERE', source);
    const tmpFilePath = path_1.default.join(tmpDir, `FunctionsScript-${Date.now()}.ts`);
    fs_1.default.writeFileSync(tmpFilePath, script);
    return tmpFilePath;
};

but not read by Deno in
const simulation = (0, child_process_1.spawn)('deno', [
        'run',
        '--no-prompt',
        `--v8-flags=--max-old-space-size=${maxMemoryUsageMb}`,
        '--allow-net',
        scriptPath,
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(secrets ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(args ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(bytesArgs ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        numAllowedQueries.toString(),
        maxQueryDurationMs.toString(),
        maxQueryUrlLength.toString(),
        maxQueryRequestBytes.toString(),
        maxQueryResponseBytes.toString(),
    ]);

That means deno was not correctly installed.
In my case when i enter in the terminale the command "deno", i could have seen the version etc. But the problem disappeared when i reinstalled deno correctly for ubuntu as i use wsl ubuntu. Double check the deno documentation according to your windows or linux set-up.
